# t-sql getting leaf nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Based on following table (I have kept spaces between the rows for clarity)

```
Path
-----------
\node1\node2\node3
\node1\node2\node3\node5

\node1\node6\node3

\node1\node4\node3
\node1\node4\node3\node7
\node1\node4\node3\node8
\node1\node4\node3\node9
\node1\node4\node3\node9\node10
```

I want to get all the paths containing leaf node. So for instance, following will be considered leaf nodes
for path \node1\node4\node3

```
\node1\node4\node3\node7
\node1\node4\node3\node8
\node1\node4\node3\node9\node10
```

The following will be the output:

```
Output
---------------------------
\node1\node2\node3\node5
\node1\node6\node3
\node1\node4\node3\node7
\node1\node4\node3\node8
\node1\node4\node3\node9\node10
```

Pls. suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find all the leaves, which are all the paths which aren't contained in any other paths. You can do this by checking for each path whether there is another path that contains it, as follows:

```
SELECT Path FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM Table1 T2
    WHERE T2.Path LIKE T1.Path + '\%'
)
```

Results:

```
Path
\node1\node2\node3\node5
\node1\node6\node3
\node1\node4\node3\node7
\node1\node4\node3\node8
\node1\node4\node3\node9\node10
```

Answer (score 0):

A `like` clause would appear to do the trick:

```
select Path
from YourTable
where Path like '%\node3\%'
or Path like '%\node3'
or Path like 'node3\%'
```

Comment: only node1 can be taken for granted. Remaining nodes can have any other value. Also number of nodes are not fixed.

Comment: As long a high performance over a large quantity of data isn't an issue!

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: `like '%\node3\%` takes care of node3 in any middle position.  The other two are for first and last position